# Is it possible to assign a Vendor to a product programmatically?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to assign a vendor to a product programmatically by using their ids. Apparently, Vendors are a type of taxonomy so I tried to use the wp_set_object_terms function but it doesn't seem to work. I tried it this way:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $vendor_id, "dc_vendor_shop", true);
```

I found the slug in [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-is-the-vendor-for-each-product-stored/) forum where they get the information using this function

```
 wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'dc_vendor_shop');
```

I figured that using the same slug would do the work but it doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone confirm if I'm using the right slug for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution but here's what I've used:

This sets the vendor to the vendor/vendor manager/vendor admin that's logged in

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_logged_in_vendor(), WC_PRODUCT_VENDORS_TAXONOMY );
```

Or you can pass an ID through but it must be wrapped in the 'intval' function in order for it to work

```
$vendor_id = intval(243);
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $vendor_id, WC_PRODUCT_VENDORS_TAXONOMY );
```